# install new kernel produce the message "No space left on device" although there is free space

Tags: boot, partitioning, kernel

I compiled the kernel 4.5 and when I tried to install it using the command `dpkg -i` I get the message "No space left on device" although there is free space in boot partition

Here the output of the command `df -h` :

```
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                       1,4G  8,0K  1,4G   1% /dev
tmpfs                      288M  1,3M  287M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/mint--vg-root  291G  130G  146G  48% /
none                       4,0K     0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                       5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none                       1,5G   18M  1,4G   2% /run/shm
none                       100M   24K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1                  236M   50M  175M  22% /boot
```

and the output of `df -i`:

```
Filesystem                  Inodes   IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev                        364279     540   363739    1% /dev
tmpfs                       368151     564   367587    1% /run
/dev/mapper/mint--vg-root 19333120 1224744 18108376    7% /
none                        368151      13   368138    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                        368151       2   368149    1% /run/lock
none                        368151      57   368094    1% /run/shm
none                        368151      21   368130    1% /run/user
/dev/sda1                    62248     302    61946    1% /boot
```

How to resolve this problem ?

Best regards

Comment: It could be another device is the referent. Please check the free space on *all* your partitions. Also, what do you mean by "install it?" I vaguely recall hearing of `efibootmgr` producing this message in reference to NVRAM entries, so if you're launching the kernel directly via the EFI stub loader and a custom NVRAM/`efibootmgr` entry, the issue could be a filled NVRAM store.

Comment: What about your root partition?  The kernel also installs a lot of modules to /lib, which takes up quite a bit of room.  If you have debug symbols enabled, that size can be very large ( > 1 GB ).

Answer (score 0):

You're having an inode problem.  You probably have many small files somewhere that is using a very small amount of space.  Each of the files are using up your inodes.

You can get your inode count with this command:

```
$ df -i
```

Check out this link to help you to locate where you inodes are being used:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347620/where-are-all-my-inodes-being-used

Comment: Not likely on /boot, which generally does not have many files.